# When I press ctrl-p and autocomplete a word, is there a way to immediately jump into normal mode by pressing escape without canceling the selection?

Tags: autocompletion, plugin-ctrlp

I use ctrl-p (and SuperTab with it), quite often to do autocompletion. But what happens quite often is that I press tab to autocomplete, I get the match I want, and then I have to go into normal mode. But when I press escape, it cancels out of the autocompletion. Is there anyway to select the autocompletion choice and then go into normal mode immediately without it canceling?

I know continuing to type will accept the autocompletion by default, but quite often I need to jump to a word, delete it, and type out another word, and then jump back to normal mode (I'd imagine I'm not alone in this). It would be useful to have tab autocompletion available in this scenario.

So is there anything I can press to accept the autocompletion and go into normal mode, without canceling it?

Comment: Selecting a suggestion *always* leaves you in insert mode. Insert mode completion would be useless if it left you in normal mode after completion.

Comment: In the title and first paragraph you say you want to go to normal mode, but at the end of the first paragraph and in the last paragraph you say you want to go to insert mode. Which is it? O.o

Comment: I'm sorry I mistyped. I just want a way to autocomplete my word and then go into normal mode immediately after.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `ctrl-e` to cancel a selection, and `ctrl-y` to accept it (followed by `ESC` to go to normal mode). People usually use `ESC` to *cancel* a selection (escape from whatever happens), and also map `Enter` to complete a selection, if one is active:

```
inoremap <expr> <silent> <cr> pumvisible() ? "<c-y>" : "<cr>"
```

If you still want to "complete and go to normal mode" on hitting `ESC`, you can use something like this instead:

```
inoremap <expr> <silent> <esc> pumvisible() ? "<c-y><esc>" : "<esc>"
```

You'll probably have to rely on `ctrl-e` more now, to cancel a selection (or delete characters with `BACKSPACE`) ...

BTW, check your `ESC` mapping - I can very well complete with `ctrl-n` and use `ESC` with no problems afterwards.