# Undo <CR> in insert mode

Tags: insert-mode

Sometimes in insert mode I hit `<CR>` by mistake  and I have to hit the backspace multiple times (depends on the indentation) to get back where I was.

e.g.

```
<div>
  <p> This is some text []</p>
</div>
```

The cursor is `[]` and I hit `<CR>` :

```
<div>
  <p> This is some text 
  []</p>
</div>
```

Now I have to hit backspace twice to get back to the previous line (this case isn't so bad but it doesn't have a lot of indentation).

Do you know a better way to do ?

Comment: `ctrl+w` twice seems to work and be pretty easy

Answer (score 10, accepted):

How about:

```
inoremap <C-\> <C-o>:left 0<Cr><BS>
```

`<C-o>` will execute a normal mode command (`:left 0`), which will remove all indent, this will also put your cursor at the start of the line. `<BS>` will get you back to the last line.

This is a bit like a "backwards `J`".

Unfortunately, mapping Shift+Enter or Ctrl+Enter doesn't seem possible, so I choose `<C-\>`, as being "near the enter".

Comment: "Near the enter" depends on your keyboard: UK ones have `\` next to the left-hand shift :-)

Comment: Why not use `<C-u>` instead of `<C-o>:left 0<CR>`?

Comment: @jamessan This works as a "backwards `J`": So `foo<CR>bar<C-\>` will leave you with `foobar`. IMHO it's more useful, but YMMV.

Comment: Right, but what I'm saying is that `<C-u>` (i.e., [i_CTRL-U](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/insert.txt.html#i_CTRL-U)) should be the same as `<C-o>:left 0<CR>`.

Comment: @jamessan Well, that depends on the cursor position. Typing `foo<CR>bar<C-u>` will leave you with `foo<CR>` (+ any auto-indent that Vim may have added). `<C-o>:left 0<CR>` will always behave the same regardless of the cursor position.

Comment: You could leave out the 0. Alternative mapping: `inoremap <f5> <c-o>^<c-u><bs>`

Answer (score 22):

I have this in my `vimrc`, the second part is relevant:

```
inoremap <expr> <silent> <cr> pumvisible() ? "<c-y>" : "<c-g>u<cr>"
```

What this does: everytime you hit `Enter` in insert mode, it will also "break the undo sequence, start new change" (see `h: i_CTRL-G_u`). This means, if you hit `Enter` by mistake, you *can* now undo your change without removing previous inserted lines, either with `ESC u a`, or with `Ctrl-o u`, as Statox proposed. Basically, each line can be undone separately.

[source](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Make_Vim_completion_popup_menu_work_just_like_in_an_IDE)

EDIT/UPDATE: If you happen to use Vim emulation in Emacs, a.k.a. *evil-mode*, you can use [this package](https://github.com/VanLaser/evil-nl-break-undo) for a similar effect.

Comment: Now I'm curious about the first part and how `<c-y>` relates to the pop-up menu.

Comment: See this answer: http://vi.stackexchange.com/a/3844/1800 . `Ctrl-y` in insert mode will complete the current popup selection, and the above mapping will allow `Enter` to complete too.

Comment: Nice trick.  However, I'd probably replace the last part `"<c-g>u<cr>"` by `&paste ? "<cr>" : "<c-g>u<cr>"`, otherwise next time you paste by mistake 200 lines of HTML you'll have a lot of fun undoing it. :)

Comment: everything can be improved ;) never happened to me so far though (I usually paste from normal mode)

Comment: Actually, I just tested with `set paste` and ... it seems to do something "magic" itself, by undoing the whole insert session in one go (as if the `CR` insert mode mapping is ignored)

Comment: ... and the explanation: when `paste` is on, Insert mode mappings are disabled (as per Vim's help)

Comment: I like this solution better because the other solutions relying on Backspace, Ctrl-W, and Ctrl-U might not work depending on how the `backspace` option is set.

Answer (score 6):

The way I do it is <kbd>Ctrl-w</kbd><kbd>Backspace</kbd>.

<kbd>Ctrl-w</kbd> to delete the last word (I forgot if this is standard vim or not), and since it's just spaces it will take me back to the beginning of the line. Then <kbd>Backspace</kbd> will take me back to the previous line where I was.

Comment: Sweet, I didn't know about the `Ctrl-w`use in insert-mode. But the  Carpetsmoker♦ is still quicker. Thus the default binding of `Ctrl-\\`doesn't seems that useful.

Comment: Ctrl+w is "standard Vim" ;-) See: [`:help i_CTRL-W`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/insert.txt.html#i_CTRL%2dW). And pressing it twice seems to do the trick as well?

Comment: I just saw on the help page that `<C-u>` may be more usefull as it deletes all the characters on the new line

Answer (score 2):

My way out of this is (from insert mode) <kbd>Up</kbd><kbd>Ctrl-o</kbd><kbd>J</kbd><kbd>Del</kbd>.  Possibly not the most efficient combination, but it's what I'm doing without needing to think about it.

Comment: Also see: [How to join lines without producing a space?](http://vi.stackexchange.com/q/439/51).

Comment: Yes, to undo <CR>, the use of `J` (:help J) is simpler than others, IMO. I do the same.